# Error creating foreign key on users_id (check data types)

Tags: mysql, laravel

Although my data types are same then why it returns me that error

```
Error creating foreign key on users_id (check data types)
```

In foreign table users_id is int 50 and unsigned and in user table id is primary key and int 50

Comment: The size and sign of fixed precision types such as INTEGER and DECIMAL must be the same.- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `id()` method to create the id in a laravel migration, the related foreign key field on the other table should use the `unsignedBigInteger()`.

You can also use `foreignId()`;

https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#column-method-foreignI